# Proper syntax for using match in Scenario

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate for my mock service, so my karate files have Scenarios that include the params I need to match to run that scenario.  I've had success with things like:
pathMatches('my/api/path') && methodIs('post') && (karate.match("json.array[*].key contains null").pass

I now want to add something like 'or json.array[*].key == #isnotpresent' based on what I found in this article: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/270

It looks like you use the match keyword in the body of a test, but how could I do this in the Scenario?  Use karate.match()?  If so, what's the proper syntax?  I know I'll need to do this kind of stuff more, so I want to get a handle on it.

I tried something like: `karate.match('json.array[*] contains { key: 'notpresent'}').pass`
and `karate.match('json.array[*] == {key: '#notpresent'}').pass` without success.

I'm using 0.9.6 version of Karate that I found when I asked this question: [Matching key value pairs in a request in a Karate Netty scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63625877/matching-key-value-pairs-in-a-request-in-a-karate-netty-scenario)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two tips:

a) Test your `Scenario` expressions in a normal Karate test like this:

```
* def temp = 
"""
{
    "Array": [

        {
            "Id": "legitId"
        },
        {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ],
}
"""
#  
* assert karate.match("temp.Array[*].Id contains null").pass || !karate.match("each temp.Array contains { Id: '#present' }").pass
```

b) You can define functions in the `Background` and use in `Scenario` expressions:

```
Background:
* def isIdMissing = function(){ return karate.match("request.Array[*].Id contains null").pass || !karate.match("each request.Array contains { Id: '#present' }").pass }

Scenario: pathMatches('my/api/path') && methodIs('post') && isIdMissing()
```