# Intercepting multiple graphql operations in a karate UI scenario always returns the first response from mock feature

Tags: karate

My scenario in the top feature file looks like this:

**Scenario: Fetch a cat type id and create a cat**

```
* driver.intercept({ patterns: [{ urlPattern: '*api/graphql*'}], mock: 
'Mock.feature' })

When I click on the button to add a cat (//first graphql call happens. This gets cat types from the mock as expected)

And input a name

And select the cat type

And click create  (//second graphql call happens here. But this returns the cat types again)

Then I see a success message
```

**Here is the mock.feature:**

Scenario: karate.match("request contains operationName: 'getCatTypes'")

- def response = call read ('response.json')

Scenario: karate.match("request contains operationName: 'AddCat'")

- def response = call read ('response1.json')

We use karate standalone jar and on version v1.2.0.RC1 (tried with 1.1.0 as well).

Appreciate any suggestions/directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `karate.match()` is wrong, note that it does not directly return a boolean. Read this for more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350442/143475

Try this change:

```
Scenario: karate.match("request contains operationName: 'getCatTypes'").pass
```

I also think there are much better ways to do the above, so read this also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63708918/143475

Comment: Thank you for answering this promptly. The solution worked! I also made a slight change (added curly braces around the operation name) in the match statement as well. My updated mock.feature :

Background:
* def getCatTypes = function() {return karate.match("request contains {operationName: 'getCatTypes'}").pass}

* def addCat = function() {return karate.match("request contains {operationName: 'AddCat'}").pass}

Scenario: getCatTypes()
* def response = call read ('getCatTypes.json')

Scenario: addCat()
* def response = call read ('addCat.json')